# How to do a leave-one-out cross validation for CAP/capscale in R vegan?

Tags: r, classification, cross-validation, predict, vegan

I would like to perform a "leave-one-out cross validation" (LOO-CV) for a CAP in R. The CAP was calculated by using `capscale` in R package `vegan` and is a canonical analysis of principal coordinates, similar to an rda or cca, but based on another similarity matrix, in my case Bray-Curtis. I have found that within `predict.cca`  there is the function `calibrate.cca` but I cannot make it work.
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/vegan/versions/2.4-2/topics/predict.cca

This is what I have (based on the sample data `mite` available in vegan)

```
library(vegan)
data(mite, mite.env)
str(mite.env) #"SubsDens", "WatrCont", "Substrate", "Shrub", "Topo"

miteBC <- vegdist(mite, method="bray") #Bray-Curtis similarity matrix
miteCAP <-capscale(miteBC~Substrate + Shrub + Topo, data=mite.env,  #CAP in capscale
                   distance = "bray", metaMDSdist = F)
summary(miteCAP)
anova(miteCAP)
anova(miteCAP, by = "axis")
anova(miteCAP, by = "margin")

calibrate.cca(miteCAP, type =  c("response")) #error cannot find function calibrate.cca
```

In the program Primer it is done automatically within the CAP function ("Leave-one-out Allocation of Observations to Groups"), where it assigns each sample automatically to a group and get a mis-classification error (similar to a classification `randomForest`, which I have already done), but I would like to use R, and it should be possible with vegan::capscale.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Function `vegan::calibrate` does not have argument `type` and never returns `"response"`. Check its documentation. It does the environmental calibration, and returns the predicted values of constraints (Substrate, Shrub, Topo) in the scale of model matrix, and with factors these hardly make sense directly.

There is no direct option of LOO: you got to do it by hand cycling through points, and using the complete left-out-point as the `newdata`. However, I'd suggest *k*-fold cross-validation as a better alternative for estimation of predictive power: LOO changes data too little, and gives over-optimistic view of predictive power.